# How to implement bindings in Apache Netbeans without org.jdesktop.beansbinding

Tags: java, netbeans, binding, netbeans-9

Support for bindings seems to have been completely removed from Netbeans 9+ when it was taken over by Apache.

The previously available org.jdesktop.beansbinding module is gone, so it the right-click menu Bind option, and the Binding tab in the Properties editor.

I have one button and one menu item that I would like to bind together so that when I change the "enabled" property on one, it changes the "enabled" property on the other automatically.

Is there a way to do that using Netbeans, and if so, could you explain how to do it?

If not, is it something I'd have to code from scratch, and again, how would I go about doing this?